# deduplicate SQL query using ROW NUMBER() method

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a scenario where our SFMC instance is receiving leads daily from Salesforce through the synchronized lead object data source.

these leads are ingested into salesforce from several third party sources and almost on a daily basis result in duplicate leads being synced to SFMC.

since the main focus for us is email communications, we would like to deduplicate records that have the same email addresses and leverage the created date field to only the ones created most recently.

Throughout my research i have learned this is possible using the row number() sql query method but i am a beginner in sql and would like some help regarding writing the code properly.

ultimately we would like to have a data extension that contains the deduped leads and the ones who had no duplicates.

and a query that we can run daily that appends new deduped leads queried from the lead synced DE.

i would truly be grateful if someone could help write this code for my educational purpose.

thank you

Comment: You should be looking into fixing this at the source, utilizing appropriate deduplication rules in Sales Cloud: https://www.salesforce.com/blog/prevent-duplicate-records-blog/